# Blender always crashes when I start working in sculpting mode

Tags: objects, interface, import, sculpt, zbrush

Blender always crashes when I start working in sculpting mode, it works good in other modes like object and edit mode but it crashes in sculpting mode, and my laptop does not have any issue related to storage. What do I do?

It only crashes after I use the brushes, on the object, if I do not do anything on the object while in sculpting nothing goes wrong.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? I would suggest either updating Blender if you are on an old version or downgrading to an earlier version if you are completely up to date.